# XSLT calling the template when it has param and it has not

Tags: xslt

In my working xslt, I have scenario as follows in some of the files

```
<xsl:template name="content">
 <xsl:param name="request" as="node()" select="doc('')"/>
    <div class="main-group">
      <div class="main container" id="main_content">

        something goes here..

      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

In some xslt, this template might have param 'request' and in some xslt, this might not have, i mean, as follows.

```
<xsl:template name="content">
     <!--param missing here-->
        <div class="main-group">
          <div class="main container" id="main_content">

            something goes here..

          </div>
        </div>
</xsl:template>
```

So, in these both case, I need to call this template [name="content"] without having trouble.

I used as follows:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="content">
     <xsl:with-param name="request" select="$request"/>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
 <xsl:call-template name="content"/>
```

My aim is to call the template named 'content' without having trouble even if the template does have param named 'request' or it does not have param 'request'

Is this Okay? Can I have any idea if this may the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 it is [an error](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTSE0680) to try and pass a (non-tunnel) parameter with `call-template` to a template that doesn't declare that parameter.

It was not an error in XSLT 1.0, in that case the undeclared parameter would simply be ignored.

It is *not* an error to pass an undeclared [*tunnel* parameter](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params) to a `call-template`, so that may be one way around the problem - use `tunnel="yes"` on both the `with-param` in the call and (if present) the `param` in the template.  But be sure you understand how tunnel parameters work and are confident that they won't cause other problems elsewhere in your stylesheet.

Comment: @lan Roberts: Is this method OKay? Will it satisfy my aim? pls share

Comment: @Sakthivel sorry, I misread your original question, the answer is no, it's not OK in XSLT 2.0 (though it is in 1.0).